# Screenshot with python pyautogui on windows - how to prevent opening shell or cmd

Tags: python, shell, cmd, screenshot, pyautogui

I want to take a screenshot with python using pyautogui. This is my code:

```
import pyautogui
im1 = pyautogui.screenshot("my_screen.png")
```

My problem is that this way half of my screen is blocked by the python shell, which pops up when I start the code. So the picture doesn´t really is a screenshot. Prior I have used python.exe to run python files and then the problem was the cmd window poping up. Now I use pythonw.exe, because apparently this prevents the cmd window to show up, but now the python shell window blocks my screen.

So does anyone know how I can take a clean screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution was quite simple. After trying to take a screenshot with pillow I got the same result. So the answear is in the configuration of Spyder, which I was using. Under configuration and "run" you can change where the code will run. And I had chosen that the code shall ran in a external window. So I changed to internal and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

make it sleep for 5 seconds maybe? enough to minimize what is not necessary to capture

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.sleep(5)
im1 = pyautogui.screenshot("my_screen.png")
```